# STM32G4 CRC peripheral. How to select Polynomial for CRC?

Tags: stm32, crc

I am working with STM32G491RE. I need to calculate CRC16 for data to send it through UART.
How do I select the CRC polynomial? Can you please suggest if there is any reference to select the poly?
Can I take the initial value as 0xFFFF, is it works or any difference values I need to take?

Comment: A complicated subject, start with these: 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check  http://zlib.net/crc_v3.txt

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not specifically about EE (for this site) but is more related to coding and math.

Comment: @Andyaka Actually the industry standard polynomials were supposedly designed to look as little as common EMI errors on the given medium as possible, i.e. to be as efficient against spikes and burst errors as possible. So there's an EE aspect to it. How much of that that's "mumbo jumbo" is another question though, since the most common 16 bit one was developed for old X.25 in the 1970s.

Comment: Another resource that includes public domain code. My team used this on a project. https://barrgroup.com/downloads/code-crc-c

Answer (score 2):

I was once doing some research on the suitability of various CRC16 for the purpose of UART, where the goal was to compare the industry standard "CRC16-CCITT" 0x1021 poly and 0xFFFF initial value vs some home-brewed OEM version, also 16 bit. Unfortunately the study is proprietary so I can't share the details, but essentially I did this:

I modeled a UART frame (start, 1 stop, no parity) in software and "bombarded" it with various forms of errors, such as single-bit, double-bit and burst, taking in account that bit errors in the start/stop bits would be detected as overrun/framing errors etc. Whereas all bits in between are just sampled per the given baudrate. Also most EMI errors aren't so kind as to just flip one bit, they usually flip several, whereas CRC excel at detecting single bit errors in particular.

The outcome of the study was that there was no notable difference between CRC16-CCITT and the OEM one was found. Both were great at spotting single-bit errors but got worse at error detection the larger the burst errors got.

Still, you should pick an industry standard one just for the sake of following standards. The main advantage of CRC16-CCITT is that some MCUs have hardware support for it in the form of a peripheral. Please also note that there are several flavours of this CRC floating around, some reversing the poly, some not initializing the checksum to 0xFFFF etc.

Another common pitfall is that CRC by its nature demands big endian, since the bitwise XOR starts at the MSB. So if you grab some random code from the Interwebs and run it on a little endian STM32, it might not give the correct results because of that alone. When writing code for data communication, always consider the *network endianess*. Which in case of UART could be anything.

Comment: Well researched, and mathematically proven CRC polynomials, such as CRC16-CCITT, are guaranteed to detect all burst errors of length <r, were r is the degree of the polynomial.  They also detect many burst errors of length >r.  I doubt you can verify this with a home-grown CRC method, regardless of how many tests are run.

Comment: @SteveSh I don't know what you mean with "degree". In my study carried out on UART frames, it failed to detect approximately 10% of all burst errors with a bit length of between 4 to 7 bits. The OEM polynomial had exactly the same error detection capabilities. And since the burst errors were injected anywhere on the UART frame including start/stop, the ~10% number fail rate is forgiving, since errors on the start/stop were regarded as always detected.

Comment: Also note that in the real world where EMI exists, disturbances aren't so kind as to leave the checksum part of the message well alone. A burst error inside the checksum tends to knock everything out. But also in the real world, EMI isn't clocked with the same source as the data either, so it will not tidily flip a number of bits (unless we are talking CRC on memory).

Comment: "Degree" is how many bits are in the polynomial that defines the CRC.  In the case of CRC-CCITT and CRC-16 (two different polynomials), there are 16-bits in the polynomial, so the degree is 16.

Comment: And a properly implemented CRC also protects against bit or burst errors that occur in the CRC itself.  Because at the receiving end, when you calculate the CRC on the data, it won't match the CRC that's appended to the message.

Comment: @SteveSh "Because at the receiving end, when you calculate the CRC on the data, it won't match the CRC that's appended to the message." This is exactly where probability kicks in. CRC is calculated on the whole frame including FCS and if the result is zero, the frame is valid. The more bits that have flipped, the higher the probability of failing. Now of course in case of software you can calculate the FCS on the payload and compare it with FCS of the frame, but that's not how CRC theory works and that's not how hardware-checking CRC works either.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of widely used 16-bit CRC equations (algorithms) out there.  CRC-16 was used in IBM's bysync protocol.  And CRC-CCITT is used in Xmodem, X.25, HDLC, and SDLC (data link protocols).

Either one of those should work fine for you.  Just keep in mind that besides the polynomial used, both sender and receiver have to agree on:

- The initial value for the CRC register
- Should the CRC be complimented or not, before being appended to the message
- The order in which the CRC bytes are appended to the message (which byte first)
- Whether or not the bits within each byte of the message are reflected (reversed) or not.

Comment: Yes, good bullets. One more potential issue. Parallel algorithms may use data sizes larger than the data stream. The sender and receiver need to pad the same.

Comment: Good point.  When I was working on the above, the data was always 16-bit words, with unused bits in a word being filled with zero.

Comment: And like so many things in engineering, it's the little things that can trip you up.

Answer (score 1):

CRC polynomials and their use is discussed in detail in many papers, books and articles, however one that in particular looks at CRC use in embedded systems. One such paper is by P Koopman, T Chakravarty. *"Cyclic Redundancy Code (CRC) Polynomial Selection For Embedded Networks"*. You have a table at the end that allows you to select an optimal one for your payload size vs hamming weights. Choose one that suits your transmission requirements that also does the best job.

Another good reference could be DOT/FAA/TC-14-49. *"Selection of Cyclic Redundancy Code and Checksum Algorithms to Ensure Critical Data Integrity"*. You might consider this one for more critical applications.