# Determining the best CRC polynomial generator regardless the input data

Tags: binary, crc

I'm given a couple of 16-bit CRC generator polynomial:

\begin{align}
g(p) &= p^{16} + p^{12} + p^5 + 1 \\
g'(p) &= p^{16} + p^{10} + p^8 + p^7 + p^3 + 1
\end{align}

And, without knowing the length or format of the input data, I'm tasked with choosing a CRC polynomial without performing any further calculations. The only answer that comes to mind is the first one, as the register block would be less complex (two adders vs. four adders). However, I'm not certain if there is a way to determine the efficiency of a CRC polynomial without any calculations.

Comment: May want to look at my answer here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/685377/stm32g4-crc-peripheral-how-to-select-polynomial-for-crc/685422#685422

Answer (score 3):

> I'm tasked with choosing a CRC polynomial without performing any further calculations.

Welcome to the world of very strange homework assignments! Of course in any reasonable real-world application, you'd do calculations, them being basically no effort at all.

- Check whether the polynomials are \$(x+1)\cdot P_g(p)\$, where \$P_g(p)\$ is a primitive polynomial of a lower degree than \$g(p)\$

  - you want an even number of terms, because you'll automatically catch all uneven-weight bit errors
- since this is a darn short 16 bit polynomial you can just actually *try* the number of bitflips your polynomial can detect, or vice versa, how much input you can run the CRC while still being able to guarantee a number of detected bitflips.

Because the latter still would much benefit from accelerated hardware implementation (guess what CPUs these days can do…), people have taken the time and tested that for your enjoyment.

So, instead of calculating, you check whether you polynomial appears in [Koopman's listing](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/%7Ekoopman/crc/crc16.html) (not the notation of that polynomial might not be what you expect), and look which of the present polynomials have better distance (i.e., error detection) properties for *your specific use case*.

There's no *generally* good polynomial; you need to know what you want to detect. Is it more important that you detect a single bitflip in a very long sequence of bits? Or that you detect, say, 5 bitflips in a shorter sequence?

Anyways, a typical hex representation of your two polynomials can be found by (pseudocode/valid python) `hex((1<<16)+(1<<12)+(1<<5)+1)` and `hex((1<<16)+(1<<10)+(1<<8)+(1<<7)+(1<<3)+1)` You'll find them on this quite commonly used [List of 16 bit CRC polynomials](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/%7Ekoopman/crc/crc16.html) by Philip Koopman.

Both are used by real-world systems.

You'll notice that one of them is much much worse for 3 and 4 bit flips (i.e., you can only detect them in drastically shorter input data), but the other still detects 5 and 6 bit flips in sequences of limited length.

So, again. This is a strange assignment (you're given algebra and then are said you're not allowed to do algebra), and it's totally underdefined, because you've not been told what you need the check to detect, specifically. "Bit errors" come in different amounts, and so does "input data".

One aside:

> The only answer that comes to mind is the first one, as the register block would be less complex (two adders vs. four adders).

don't forget you're in GF(2), so your "adder" is a single XOR gate. I wouldn't know in which possible context the difference between 4 or 6 XORs would really matter.

Answer (score 0):

The first one you listed is the CRC-CCITT, which is widely used in protocols such as XMODEM, X.25, HDLC, and SDLC.  It has been thoroughly researched and analyzed, so that's the one I would choose.

Comment: Thanks, steveSh. At the end, I come to the conclusion that it's more of a question about finding bibliography rather than a mathematical question. I remember a quite famous article that I've seen cited many times around here (I can't recall the name right now) where it analyzes the performance of various 16-CRC polynomials based on input data, so I imagine it must be related to this.

Comment: Note that a lot of the older standard CRC polynomials are known to be quite bad, compared to other, also exhaustively investigated polynomials. Mathematicians simply tried all possible 16 bit CRC polynomials, and exhaustively tested all of their error detection capabilities, there's no need to "rely on things that worked well in the past" – we can tell, mathematically certain, how well each polynomial works.

Comment: (My favourite example is CRC-32 "HDLC/Ethernet/SATA/GZIP/MPEG2…", probably the most widely used CRC in software. it gets its remainder handed to it by CRC-32 Castagnoli on long data (which is why storage systems use Castagnoli's CRC32 and not the "standardized" CRC32), and for Ethernet frame lengths (where it should *really* work, you know, that being kind of an important use) by a Koopman-chosen 32 bit CRC. 
CRC-CCITT-16 is not bad for 4-weight errors, but there's polynomials with the same weight-3 and weight-4 performance, which can, unlike CCIT-16, still detect up to 13 errors – for free.)